anchor build error with path in windows
I have seen error like this here.
but i cannt find correct solution.
so i post this question again
error is as follow:
[2024-05-28T02:18:40.570816900Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to obtain package metadata: cargo metadata exited with an error: error: failed to load manifest for workspace member \\?\E:\anchor\test\programs\*
referenced by workspace at \\?\E:\anchor\test\Cargo.toml
Caused by:
  failed to read `\\?\E:\anchor\test\programs\*\Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)

error happened in windows.
in my thought, this is path problem.
when anchor build, it doesnt go to correct path.
we can see path of cargo.toml file.
i want correct solution.
Thanks
